# How to wrap text inside a circle?

Tags: android, canvas, text, android-canvas, word-wrap

Is there a direct way to wrap text inside a circle. Using drawTextOnPath I get to write around the circle but not inside it.

like this:
[image]

Comment: Check this and modify the same to your requirement. https://github.com/lisawray/circletextview or have a custom view and do all the the calculations and draw the text yourself